# window is not defined vuejs and vuetify SSR

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

getting error  while adding/integrating Vuetify like.. import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib' Vue.use(Vuetify) in main.js

main.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

Answer (score 2):

change loader in  webpack from

```
.........
  module: {
    rules: [
     {
       test: /\.styl$/,
       loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
     },
   .....
```

to

```
  .........
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.styl$/,
            loader: ['css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
        },
    .....
```

remove 'style-loader' loader

to install loaders

```
 npm i stylus-loader  css-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: @D V Yogesh Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524595/how-can-i-implement-server-side-rendering-ssr-on-the-vuetify-project-that-is-1